# Converting Powerpoint slides to an HTML slide show

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Converting Powerpoint slides to an HTML slide show.
Is there anyway to do this for static slides that are just text and images?
This is Powerpoint 2010.  I can't seem to find the option is Save As.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft removed saving powerpoint slides as HTML in Office 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/publish-your-presentation-to-the-web-HA010338333.aspx). But there is sort of a kludgy workaround that produces hideously terrible web pages.

You can publish your slideshow as a handout in Word and then export from there to the web.

If you think those web pages are of insufficient quality you may be better off either publishing to PDF and making that available or using OpenOffice to publish to HTML.